# apt-get purge libc6-dev-i386 want to remove important packages

Tags: apt, purge

I had problem when compiling 32-bit ELF inside 64-bit Ubuntu. This is error message produced by GCC compiler :

```
cheap-laptop@my-machine:~/DEV-DIR$ gcc -m32 test.c -o test
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:374:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

I searched Google for this problem and found that `libc6-dev-i386` must be installed first.

I installed it and had no luck, and same error still occurred. So I had Google again and found this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225701).

It suggested to remove purge `libc6-dev` and install it back using `apt-get`. Then, some message appeared and it look like this :-

```
cheap-laptop@my-machine:~/DEV-DIR$ sudo apt-get purge libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 icu-devtools libboost-atomic1.54.0
  libboost-chrono1.54.0 libboost-context1.54.0 libboost-filesystem1.54.0
  libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0 libboost-graph1.54.0 libboost-iostreams1.54.0
  libboost-locale1.54.0 libboost-log1.54.0 libboost-math1.54.0
  libboost-mpi-python1.54.0 libboost-mpi1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0
  libboost-python1.54.0 libboost-random1.54.0 libboost-regex1.54.0
  libboost-serialization1.54.0 libboost-signals1.54.0 libboost-test1.54.0
  libboost-thread1.54.0 libboost-timer1.54.0 libboost-tools-dev
  libboost-wave1.54.0 libboost1.54-tools-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2
  libdbus-1-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libgssrpc4 libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libibverbs-dev libice-dev libidn11-dev
  libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9 libkdb5-7 libp11-kit-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libssl-doc libtasn1-6-dev
  libtinfo-dev libvala-0.22-0 libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev
  libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev
  libxml2-utils libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev mpi-default-bin valac-0.22-vapi
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  comerr-dev* gcc-4.9-multilib* gcc-multilib* krb5-multidev* libatk1.0-dev*
  libboost-all-dev* libboost-atomic-dev* libboost-atomic1.54-dev*
  libboost-chrono-dev* libboost-chrono1.54-dev* libboost-context-dev*
  libboost-context1.54-dev* libboost-coroutine-dev*
  libboost-coroutine1.54-dev* libboost-date-time-dev*
  libboost-date-time1.54-dev* libboost-dev* libboost-exception-dev*
  libboost-exception1.54-dev* libboost-filesystem-dev*
  libboost-filesystem1.54-dev* libboost-graph-dev*
  libboost-graph-parallel-dev* libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev*
  libboost-graph1.54-dev* libboost-iostreams-dev* libboost-iostreams1.54-dev*
  libboost-locale-dev* libboost-locale1.54-dev* libboost-log-dev*
  libboost-log1.54-dev* libboost-math-dev* libboost-math1.54-dev*
  libboost-mpi-dev* libboost-mpi-python-dev* libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev*
  libboost-mpi1.54-dev* libboost-program-options-dev*
  libboost-program-options1.54-dev* libboost-python-dev*
  libboost-python1.54-dev* libboost-random-dev* libboost-random1.54-dev*
  libboost-regex-dev* libboost-regex1.54-dev* libboost-serialization-dev*
  libboost-serialization1.54-dev* libboost-signals-dev*
  libboost-signals1.54-dev* libboost-system-dev* libboost-system1.54-dev*
  libboost-test-dev* libboost-test1.54-dev* libboost-thread-dev*
  libboost-thread1.54-dev* libboost-timer-dev* libboost-timer1.54-dev*
  libboost-wave-dev* libboost-wave1.54-dev* libboost1.54-dev* libc6-dev*
  libc6-dev-i386* libc6-dev-x32* libcairo2-dev* libcurl4-openssl-dev*
  libdbus-glib-1-dev* libdbusmenu-glib-dev* libdee-dev* libexpat1-dev*
  libfontconfig1-dev* libfreetype6-dev* libgcrypt11-dev* libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev*
  libgee-0.8-dev* libglib2.0-dev* libgnutls-dev* libgpgme11-dev*
  libgtk2.0-dev* libhwloc-dev* libicu-dev* libkrb5-dev* libncurses5-dev*
  libncursesw5-dev* libnotify-dev* libopenmpi-dev* libpango1.0-dev*
  libpcap-dev* libpcap0.8-dev* libpci-dev* libpcre3-dev* libpng12-dev*
  libpython-dev* libpython2.7-dev* librtmp-dev* libsqlite3-dev* libssh-dev*
  libssh2-1-dev* libssl-dev* libstdc++-4.8-dev* libunity-dev* libxft-dev*
  mpi-default-dev* nvidia-331* python2.7-dev* uuid-dev* valac-0.22*
  zlib1g-dev*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 107 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 506 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

It want to remove important packages such as `libboost-*`, `nvidia-331*` and others. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for some minutes, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825889) inside Stack Overflow site.

So the solution for my problem is, just use `install --reinstall [package-name]` argument when running `apt-get`, it will just reinstall you desired package without purging and downloading it back, so here is full command that solved my problem :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev-i386`

Comment: did that solve your problem compiling?

Comment: yes it's, `gcc` don't produce error anymore with `-m32` argument after reinstall `libc6-dev-i386` using above method.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted answer by clicking the icon on the left.

Comment: @mchid, actually I can't, system said only 2 days after posting I'm allowed to accept my own answer. By the way, thanks for the tip.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12)
             Recommends: gcc but it is not going to be installed or
                         c-compiler
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

The package `libc6-dev` is required to compile anything, and so most, if not all, development packages depend on that package. If you remove `libc6-dev`, then those headers will get removed as well (along with some of the libraries themselves, if nothing else depends on those libraries and were automatically installed).

Removing and reinstalling this package probably won't help you in compiling 32-bit programs from a 64-bit Ubuntu, since this package is for compiling 64-bit programs. Instead, make sure that `libc6-dev-i386` is installed. If you are still getting an error, create a new question and post the error message there.

Comment: How about it want to remove nvidia's driver too?

Comment: `nvidia-331` depends on `libc6-dev` (and on `linux-libc-dev`; don't ask me why). You can view this information by typing in `apt-cache depends nvidia-331`.

Comment: Thank you very much for willing your time for me, and I already answered my question. :)
Thank you for `apt-cache depends [package-name]` command, I never knew that.